# How to record a gunshot?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, audio-processing

My graduation work is basically to write a software to recognize a gunshot in open ambients (e.g. a city). 
I also need to develop the "audio capture" device. My idea for prototyping is to write an Android app to stream an audio format to a server running the recognition algorithm.
My doubt is: is it possible to record a gunshot and extracts its sound characteristics with a regular smartphone microphone? If don't, what kind of microphone or record system do I need?

[image]

Comment: How is *Can a gunshot be recorded on a smartphone microphone?* a programming question?

Comment: If the human ear can hear it, a smartphone can record it (although maybe not at the proper gain). The other questions is, are there frequencies greater than 20khz that are useful for feature detection in your application. (probably not?)

Comment: @KenWhite where should I ask?

Comment: @szatmary thats why I am making this question. Can a "regular smartphome microphone" record a gunshot and keep the audio characteristics like in the image? Do I need to search about good microphones or good soundboards? Or maybe I just need to record it in a proper audio coding format!?!?

Comment: I'm a bit confused and don't know what to ask for google.

Comment: Well every phone is different. A good one can, a bad one may not be able too. An external microphone will alway be better, especially for Omni directional recording. But a phones ADC is just as good and any non professional sound card will have. This is now out of scope for stackoverflow however since we are discussing hardware selection and not software development. Good luck!

Comment: Recognizing gunshot is similar to recognizing a live song. U can do it using "audio fingerprinting". Try searching for `recognize song using audio finger printing`on google. Research shazam, deja-vu etc.That will get u started.

Comment: Sounds like a good task for a neural net... you're going to need a bunch of sound samples.

Comment: Keep in mind also that real gunshots sound a lot more boring than gunshots from movies or video games. As long as your input is not peaking, you should have no problem capturing an audio recording of the sound.